# Random rows from Database

Tags: sql-server, random, distinct

I want to create a `SELECT` statement that gets 20% of the records from a table containing 50 records.

I managed to get 10 records in return, but I want the results to be *distinct*, random rows.

How can i solve this?

This is the query I have so far:

```
 SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT * FROM que ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP (20) PERCENT
       *
FROM   (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               *
        FROM   que
       ) As distinct_records
ORDER
    BY NewID()
```